# Bitrate reduction by rounding instead of truncating and dithering

Tags: bitrate, dither

From my understanding, dithering is used to mask the systematic error that one introduces by reducing the bitrate simply by truncating (i.e. chopping off) the least significant bits. This makes sense to me.

But what if instead of truncation one uses the lower bits to round instead, wouldn't that be even better for quality? So say you reduce the bit rate from 24 bit to 16 bit, use the lowest 8 bit of the 24bit sample to decide if a one is added to the truncated value (with e.g. round-to-even for the half-way point 128). That would seem like the most "correct" way to me, as it is the mathematically closest representation of the original signal in the lower bitrate.

And by using rounding instead of truncation, there may possibly be less need for dithering afterwards (when reducing to otherwise near-transparent bitrates like 16bit or above, as obviously rounding vs truncation won't matter much for easily audible quality-reducing reductions). Since the maximum amplitude of the error signal by rounding is only half of that of truncation I assume the introduced noise is more quiet, which might be quiet enough to not be noticeable at 16bit and possibly preferable over the added dither noise. So my question is, are there publicly available studies that compare the quality of truncation vs rounding (with and without dithering)?

Comment: Hi.  In reviewing your question, I can see you've got a misconception about dither, that it somehow "belongs with" truncation and you are comparing that with rounding.  In fact, what you should be comparing is rounding vs truncation period.  Dither should be used in either case.  It doesn't belong to one or the other method, but is a separate process.

Comment: @DataProcessing I understand those are separate processes, so I don't think I have a misconception there, though I may have formulated my question not clear enough. But you are right in the sense that I can generalize my question to why truncation is ever used, as rounding seems to be the obvious superior choice in general (regardless of whether dither is applied later on or not). It is just that if rounding already produces a better signal, there may be much less need to mask the errors with dithering as is with truncation, hence my original question.

Comment: The question of rounding vs truncation is already very well understood (spoiler alert: it doesn't make all that much difference, it's the dithering that makes the most difference), although I don't recall seeing it discussed on here before.  Would you like me to rewrite your question to fix the wording or would you like to do it?

Comment: Updated, it is hopefully clear enough now. If you can quote some source for the claim that it doesn't make much difference that would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can do tests like this yourself, it's actually not that difficult to do. It just takes a little bit of coding knowledge, and you can round however you want and listen to and analyse the results. (That's my idea of fun!)

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of dithering in audio processing is to hide quantizing noise. In effect the dithering moves hearable noise to frequencys where the ear is less sensitive.

Rounding has no effect on the frequency profile of the quantizing noise and gives the same effect as simply truncating.

Comment: Can you quote some source for this claim? Purely mathematically speaking, truncation is a clear bias/systematic error, whereas correctly rounding is not. In a way you could say rounding is some sort of 1-bit dithering as it will add a "one" sometimes, just instead of randomly it adds it depending on the input signal. Not saying you are wrong, but I'd like to have at least some sort of explanation why this mathematical argument is not applicable here.

Comment: It wouldn't be "correct" even in mathematical terms, @zse - we only use rounding in maths because we do not mind the error it introduces. In sound, that error is not acceptable - it is audible. You could try it and hear how annoying it would be :-)

Comment: @zse The point is the frequncy distribution of the quantization error. This article gives a bit of insight on how to calculate it https://www.scielo.org.mx/pdf/jart/v7n2/v7n2a3.pdf (way above my ability to  work through it). Ditheriing is more of a psychoacoustic processing, moving the noise to frequencys where it is less heard. One of example: https://unison.audio/dithering/#:~:text=The%20noise%20spectrum%20in%20dithering,in%20your%20final%20audio%20file. And no, rounding could perhaps decrease the noise one half bit (?) but it will not change the frequency.

Comment: @RoryAlsop it is correct in the sense that rounding will choose the closest representable value to the "perfect" source value. Truncation still seems clearly worse to me, as that disregards more information from the source signal than rounding. Even when additional dithering is still useful, it does not sound logical to me that one wouldn't want rounding, except maybe that it has been proven that rounding has a such a small quality improvement that it is not done out of practical performance reasons.

Comment: @ghellquist Thanks for those links. Though I'm not quite sure why you are convinced that rounding (vs truncation) has no impact at all on the frequency response, without a proper mathematical analysis. I guess a mathematician would have to chime in here, or I just have to take your word for it.

Comment: @zse Just to completely clear: the question is the frequency  distribution  of the quantization noise (not of the wanted signal). Notice that dithering will increase total noise, but move it to frequencies where the ear is less disturbed. I have seen nothing that would indicate that rounding would make any large impact on frequency response of the dithering noise.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I suppose my question is, has anyone actually analyzed the quantization noise that rounding produces. In my naive view rounding should usually be better than truncation, so I'm wondering if someone bothered to verify (theoretically or practically) it has no advantage over truncation, or whether we are just cargo-culting along with that truncation stuff (because the 1970 hardware was not powerful enough and could only do truncation ;).

Comment: Here is another way I look at this: bitrate reduction is basically equivalent to mixing in a quantization error signal into your source material. The maximum amplitude of the error signal when rounding is only half of the one with truncation, so even if the rounded error signal still contains the same nasty frequencies as the truncated one (that one wants to hide with dithering), this suggests that it is much more quiet. And when the error is a lot more quiet, it is much less necessary to hide it via dithering.

Comment: @zse Rounding is useful in other cases, but here it is equivalent to adding a DC offset - a zero hertz signal that is removed at the DA stage. Example (using decimal digits). Assume we have a signal going from 0.00 to 1.00 which we truncate down to 0.0 to 1.0. In order to do rounding we simply add a fixed value of 0.05 before truncating. 0.00 becomes 0.05 and truncates to 0.0. Then 0.05 adds up to 0.10 and is truncated to 0.1 (in effect rounding). And so on. Works the same with digital numbers. Try it for yourself.

Comment: True, but that does not change the fact that the rounded signal has a lower error bound than the truncated one (without the DC offset - or are you saying that all the software that does this bitrate reduction already actually implements this with DC offset and thus already in fact rounds?). Anyway, I guess this becomes too much of a discussion here, might not be the right place to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Rounding gives exactly the same sort of quantisation errors as truncation does.

You can see this because rounding is effectively the same as adding 0.5 (scaled appropriately) and then truncating.  The exact transition points shift, but the basic pattern remains.  (Rounding does avoid a *systematic* error averaging -0.5 — but that's effectively a DC shift, which inaudible.)

It's worth seeing the Wikipedia page for [Dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither#Digital_audio), which discusses this.  It uses the following values as an example:

```
0.8  1.6  2.4  3.2  4.0  4.8  5.6  6.4
```

Truncation gives:

```
0    1    2    3    4    4    5    6
```

While rounding gives:

```
1    2    2    3    4    5    6    6
```

The quantisation noise is not identical, but still has the same character, resulting in ‘additional content at discrete frequencies created by the regular and repeated quantisation error.’

The page then goes on to look at how you might *vary* the rounding to avoid that — and so derives dithering.

This may be clearer in its image examples.  In particular, truncation or rounding are illustrated in the non-dithered example:

[image: image of a cat, reduced to the 256-colour web-safe palette, with no dithering]

(The flat areas show how much detail is lost.)

Whereas the following version uses dithering — you can see how much more detail is preserved, despite having the same bit depth as the image above:

[image: same image of a cat, reduced to the 256-colour web-safe palette, but this time with Floyd-Steinberg dithering]

The effects on digital audio are perhaps less obvious, but you can see how the fairly regular, repeating errors in the first image might correspond to prominent low-frequency noise, and those in the second to noise spread more evenly across much higher frequencies where it would be much less noticeable.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, though I do understand the concept of dithering already. But your answer made me realize my question was still too imprecisely formulated, I have updated it again.

Comment: One more thing, I think you may be disregarding a DC shift before a truncation operation as unimportant prematurely, as truncation is a non-linear operation (ie DC shift before truncation does by no means result in the same thing as truncation plus DC shift afterwards). Furthermore, truncation pulls the signal towards -inf, so it gives your signal a (admittedly very slight) negative DC offset, which is another argument against using truncation and preferring rounding which doesn't do that.

Comment: @zse Depending on where the resulting signal is going, any DC bias might get completely stripped out by further encoding/compression (especially if it's based on DCT or other frequency analysis, which I think most are) or by audio hardware (converters, interfaces, amplifiers, connections).  So although it wouldn't end up being audible if it reached the listener's ears, in most cases it's unlikely to get anywhere near that far.  (contd)

Comment: …But my main point was that truncation and rounding are _equally_ bad — _both_ non-linear — and both result in the same _sort_ of quantisation noise, despite the exact numbers (and bias) being different.  Imagine, for example, the first image but with the colour bands shifted sideways slightly; it might reduce the RMS error a little, but subjectively it's just as bad.  As others have already said, the different is insignificant compared to the benefit from dithering.

Comment: I would have liked a bit less on dithering and a bit more on the different characteristics of the noise resulting from rounding vs truncating.